# Не возвращается JSON после post запроса через requests

Tags: python, веб-программирование, post, вконтакте, xmlhttprequest

Пытаюсь вытащить имена исполнителей и названия аудиозаписей из своего плейлиста вконтакте.

В консоли разработчика в хроме увидел, что при загрузке страницы с аудио (vk.com/audiosXXXXXX, где иксы это id профиля) первым делом посылается POST запрос к https://vk.com/al_audio.php. И в ответ приходит список всех аудиозаписей данного профиля:

[image: Это вся информация по запросу]
[image: А это собственно сама инфа об аудиозаписях]

Что пытался делать:

Сначала через расширение хромиума экспортировал `cookies.txt` со своими куками вконтакта, подгрузил его в `cookObj`, создал словари с хедерами и данными запроса, и сделал этот запрос. Потом просто записал ответ сервера в файл. Планировал в этом файле увидеть то же самое, что и в окне Preview/Response браузерной консоли разработчика и потом все это дело распарсить.

Вот что написал на питоне:

```
import requests
import http.cookiejar
import time

#prepare cookies
cookObj = http.cookiejar.MozillaCookieJar('./cookies.txt')
cookObj.load()
#print(len(cookObj))
for cookie in cookObj:
    cookie.expires = time.time() + 14*24*3600

url = 'https://vk.com/al_audio.php'

header =    {   
            ':authority' : 'vk.com',
            ':method' : 'POST',
            ':path' : '/al_audio.php',
            ':scheme' : 'https',
            'accept' : '*/*',
            'accept-encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language' : 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,da;q=0.2',
            'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'dnt' : '1',
            'origin' : 'https://vk.com',
            'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
            'x-compress' : 'null',
            'x-requested-with' : 'XMLHttpRequest'

        }

form =  {
        'act:' : 'load_silent',
        'al' : '1',
        'album_id' : '-2',
        'band' : 'false',
        'owner_id' : 'XXXXXXXX'
    }

resp = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=form, cookies=cookObj)
#resp.status_code

f = open('./response', 'w')
f.write(resp.text)
```

Но в итоге, в файле `response` оказывается почти пусто (остаются только какие-то неизвестные мне теги, между которыми в оригинале (в консоли разработчика было видно) должен был быть список аудиозаписей):

```
3707107324781<!><!>0<!>6762<!>5<!>1
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что не так.

Comment: Есть ведь API, с его помощью это нельзя реализовать?

Comment: А код ответа какой? 200 или какой то другой? Ну и уберите лишние заголовки. Нужно только user-agent

Comment: @m9_psy в декабре прошлого года методы работы с аудио были удалены из API вконтакта.

Comment: @rusnasonov код ответа 200. Убрал лишние хедеры, оставил только user-agent. Ситуация та же.

Comment: У урла измените схему, у вас http а надо https

Comment: @rusnasonov Хм. Действительно, спасибо. Сейчас ответ изменился - отдается html код, причем, насколько я понял - как раз с теми аудио, которые выводятся первыми при открытии страницы из браузера. Т. е., полного списка, который я мог видеть в браузерной консоли пока не имеется. Вот то, что отдается - https://pastebin.com/VC4iqLFN

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте разобрался уже с официальным апи - там я подозреваю все это делается просто, и без плясок с бубном

Comment: @rusnasonov да я бы с радостью, только вот, как я уже говорил, в официальном апи методы для работы с аудио удалены уже месяцев 5 как.

Comment: Да, точно. Не заметил. Я думаю, что выводятся только первые, потому что в браузере загружаются аудио по мере скрола страницы. Чтобы загружать остальные записи надо поскролить. Средствами requests такого не сделать. Вам нужно обратить внимание в сторону selenium, и возможно phantomjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня недавно была та же проблема, только с другим методом вк. Моя проблема была в том, что помимо куки вк присылает хеш и его также надо передать в параметрах запроса, вот обсуждение, надеюсь поможет - [Как сокращать ссылки vk.cc на python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648230/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-vk-cc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)

Comment: Хм. Спасибо большое, сегодня попробую, отпишусь!

Comment: Ага, посмотрите в Postman, он подробно показывает параметры запроса/ответа и можно поэкспериментировать с ПОСТ ГЕТ запросами

Comment: Написал программу наподобии той, что в вашем посте, и JSON в итоге смог получить. Конечно, двухфакторка мешает при залогинивании, но это все поправимо. Благодарю!

Comment: Хеш, кстати, в итоге не понадобился. Видимо, проблемы с залогиниванием через кукисы были.

Comment: Через `requests` сделали?

Comment: Да, `requests` + `re` и `json` для парсинга.