# Как сокращать ссылки vk.cc на python?

Tags: python, вконтакте

Вопрос по сокращению ссылок через vk.cc, подозреваю что что-то пропустил, в ответ получаю: `'3975786006921<!>profile.css,page.css,profile.js,page.js<!>0<!>6762<!>8<!>Невозможно сократить эту ссылку.<!><!>57500570'`
На любой адрес.
API вроде нет, расширение для Хрома у меня не завелось, не знаю работает ли оно сейчас, код ниже:

```
import requests
import re


def get_form_action(html):
    form_action = re.findall(r'<form(?= ).* action="(.+)"', html)
    if form_action:
        return form_action[0]


auth_session = requests.Session()


def authorization(phone, password):
    url = 'https://m.vk.com'
    response = auth_session.get(url)
    login_form_action = get_form_action(response.text)
    if not login_form_action:
        raise Exception('VK changed login flow')
    login_form_data = {
        'email': phone,
        'pass': password
    }
    response = auth_session.post(login_form_action, login_form_data)


def get_short(link):
    url = 'https://vk.com/cc?act=shorten&al=1&link='+link
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
    response = auth_session.post(url=url, headers=headers)
    return response.text
```

Может кто делал серверную реализацию сокращения ссылок через вк? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Вы отправляете параметры в ссылке, а надо в теле POST-запроса. А ещё экранировать `link` забываете

Comment: url = 'https://vk.com/cc'
    data = {'act': 'shorten', 'al': 1, 'link': 'test.com'}
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
    response = auth_session.post(url, data, headers=headers)

Comment: Изменил, но по прежнему получаю сообщение Невозможно сократить эту ссылку, не могли бы Вы привести пример как исправить мой код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Накидал пример того как можно авторизоваться и воспользоваться vk для получения короткой ссылки:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_short_link_from_vk(login: str, password: str, link: str) -> str:
    """
    Функция для получения короткой ссылки используя сервис vk.

    """

    def get_form_action(html: str) -> str:
        """
        Функция вернет ссылку для запроса авторизации

        """
        
        form_action = re.findall(r'<form(?= ).* action="(.+)"', html)
        if form_action:
            return form_action[0]
    
    session = requests.Session()

    # Без авторизации не получится воспользоваться страницей укорачивания ссылок
    url = 'https://m.vk.com'
    rs = session.get(url)
    print(rs)

    login_form_action = get_form_action(rs.text)
    if not login_form_action:
        raise Exception('VK изменил верстку формы логина')

    login_form_data = {
        'email': login,
        'pass': password,
    }
    rs = session.post(login_form_action, login_form_data)
    print(rs)

    # Страница нужна, чтобы получить hash для запроса
    rs = session.get('https://vk.com/cc')
    
    match = re.search(r"Shortener\.submitLink\('(.+)'\)", rs.text)
    if not match:
        raise Exception('Не удалось получить hash для Shortener')

    shortener_hash = match.group(1)

    # Данные для POST запроса для получения короткой ссылки
    data = {
        'act': 'shorten',
        'link': link,
        'al': '1',
        'hash': shortener_hash,
    }

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

    rs = session.post('https://vk.com/cc', headers=headers, data=data)
    print(rs)

    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'lxml')

    a_short_link = root.select_one('.shortened_link.shorten_list_header > a[href]')
    return a_short_link['href']
```

Использование:

```
LOGIN = '<LOGIN>'
PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>'
link = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648230'

short_link = get_short_link_from_vk(LOGIN, PASSWORD, link)
print(short_link)

link = 'https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2'
short_link = get_short_link_from_vk(LOGIN, PASSWORD, link)
print(short_link)
```

Консоль:

```
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
https://vk.cc/6sYwPq
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
<Response [200]>
https://vk.cc/5AJUvX
```

Использовал сторонние модули:

```
pip install requests
pip install bs4
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, упустил хеш для запроса, все работает!

Comment: @IgorSergeevich да я сам сначала не понял в чем дело, потом заметил хеш и попытался ссылку захешировать (md5, sha1), но близко не совпадало, тогда поискал на самой странице и нашел его, и понял что он приходит от самого vk и его нужно вытаскивать для запроса :)